# how to make observable a css class with knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

this is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
   <input type="button" id="btnEnable" value="Enable" />
   <input type="button" id="btnDisable" value="Disable" />
</div>
<div id="myDiv">Some Text</div>
<textarea rows="5" id="someText" data-bind="enable: enableText"></textarea>
```

css:

```
.enabled{
  background-color: green;
}
.disabled{
  background-color: red;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myDiv").addClass("enabled").html(" Enabled");

  $("#btnEnable").click(function () {
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("disabled");
    $("#myDiv").addClass("enabled").html(" Enabled");
  });
  $("#btnDisable").click(function () {
    $("#myDiv").addClass("disabled").html(" Disabled");
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("enabled");
  });
  var viewModel = function(){
    enableText =  ko.observable(true)
  }
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

when i click on the disable button, the enabled css class is removed. At this point, i need to disable the textarea by KO observable viewModel.

```
var viewModel = function(){
    enableText =  ko.observable(here must return false when the enable css class is removed)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the click, css and text bindings :

```
$(document).ready(
    var viewModel= function () {
        var self = this;
        self.enableClick = function () {
            self.enable(true);
        };
        self.disableClick = function () {
            self.enable(false);
        };
        // Stores the enable state
        self.enable = ko.observable();
        // Get a text representation of the state 
        self.enableText = ko.computed(function(){
           return self.enable() ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

The view  :

```
<div>
   <input type="button" data-bind="click: enableClick" value="Enable" />
   <input type="button" data-bind="click: disableClick" value="Disable" />
</div>

<div data-bind="text: enableText, css :{'enabled' : enable,'disabled' : enable() != true }">Some Text</div>
<textarea rows="5" id="someText" data-bind="enable: enable"></textarea>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w2LK/)

Comment: @pasluc74669,"something else" could you be more specific ?

Comment: it works fine, but i need something else: i need to enable/disable the textarea, by the knockout modelview, when a css class is removed/added.Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. In 99% cases it's bad idea, because KO is responsible of changing the UI. I mean you change the viewmodel and KO alter the view.